# 'Hovering' elements when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, hide, show

What I want is fairly simple, and I have two examples for it:

http://janvanderkleijn.nl/

http://studio-laucke-siebein.com/

When looking at these portfolio websites you see it's scroll based websites mainly relying on images. The interactivity I'm looking for is the clicking on an image, resulting in a 'hovering' element over the web page, further elaborating the project with text, images etc.
What I like about it is that you don't have to leave the home-page to look into a project, and it can be closed by either pressing the close button in the top right, or clicked anywhere outside of this element. Especially in Laucke-Sibein's webpage it's nice, that when you scroll far enough down, the element dissappears.

How hard is it to achieve a similar result? How does this function work? I've been looking all afternoon and failed to find something that helped me further.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) The content of your question must be **in** your question, not linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site.

Comment: This is often referred to as lightbox and there are [many](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+lightbox) jQuery plugins that make this easy.

Comment: Thanks! I thought lightboxes were used for images only. In the two examples given, were they (both) using lightbox elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others there are many jQuery plugins like lightbox, fancybox, etc. that are capable of outputting images and text. Or a jquery-ui dialog box would work.

Alternatively you could create your portfolio items inside div's and show them on click events.

```
<body>
    <div id="project-list">
        html showing images from your projects. <br />
        <img src="img1.jpg" data-project="project1" />
        <img src="img2.jpg" data-project="project2" />
    </div>
    <div id="project1" class="project">
        html displaying <br />
        your project 1
    </div>
    <div id="project2" class="project">
        html displaying <br />
        your project 2
    </div>
</body>
```

Then css something like:

```
.project { position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; display: none; }

#project-list.fixed { position: static; }
```

Then the using jQuery it would look like:

```
$(function(){
    // add click handler to the images
    $('#project-list img').click(function(e){
        // if a project is visible then just return and let the
        // document click handler handle the closing of the project
        if($('.project:visible').length > 0){
            return; 
        }
        // get the data project attribute which tells you which project to open
        var project = $(this).data('project'); 
        $('#' + project).slideDown('slow');
        // add the fixed class to the project list so that it doesn't scroll
        $('#project-list').addClass('fixed');
        // you must have this to keep the click event from bubbling up
        // through the DOM and triggering the document click function
        // which would close the project as soon as it opens. 
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function(){
        // this closes the project when anything is clicked that doesn't
        // have the event.stopPropagation function set. 
        $('.project').slideUp('slow');
        $('#project-list').removeClass('fixed');
    });

    $('.project').click(function(e){
        // you want this so if they click anything in the project it doesn't 
        // close the project. 
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

See a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wdv79yxw/1/

Comment: Sublime, this was what I've been looking for more or less the entire day. Thanks a lot Gregg!

Comment: Glad to help. If this satifies your answer please mark it as the correct answer. Have a good one.

Comment: I want to, but I began to notice that for whatever reason if I open this fiddle in a browser it doesn't work.
I tried applying it to my own code at first, but no response. I've copied it directly from jsfiddle to make sure. It looks exactly the same but without the functionality. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You must have a reference jquery in the head of your html. And you have to wrap the code in a $(function(){ ...code goes here...  }); wrapper. This is handled for you in the fiddle.

Comment: This currently is my index.html: http://puu.sh/kw4vS/d39c6038fc.png

and the script.js: http://puu.sh/kw4wT/056801d3c9.png

It results in: http://puu.sh/kw4zb/96f551aa20.png (I made two basic figures for "img1.jpg" & "img2.jpg", still without functionality. I tried it with the $(function(){ ... code goes here... }); wrapper.

I reckon it's obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your wrapper is wrong. The $(function(){  ... code goes here ...  }); is missing the left parenthesis after function. This is an anonymous function that is a shortcut for "$(document).ready(function(){". Also you don't have a reference to jQuery. You can either add it via CDN as a script tag with a src of https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js. Or you can download it  at https://jquery.com/download/ and reference it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a modal window. There are tons of jQuery libraries out there, or even pure CSS solutions. A decent one that I've used is jQuery fancybox, which supports videos, iframes, content, a gallery of images. It's very robust.

Comment: I've worked with fancybox before, and will definately have a look into them again, thanks for the comment. I thought they were mainly used for images only.